# How can I make console.log write the complete log I am passing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm debugging some javascript on my page and the log I am passing is to long and chrome adds "..." between the beginning and the end of the string.

I want to copy the content, so alert doesn't work for me and creating and html element for that it is just offensive...

any clue?

Comment: can you give an example? I just tested 2k char strings in chrome and firefox and were able to see everything in console.log()

Comment: I don´t know how to prevent this from happening in `console.log`, but if you want to copy it to the clipboard either way you could use the `copy(myvar)` from dev tools to get the full content in your clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the object that was logged, you can store it as a temporary variable. Like so:

[image: Selecting a logged variable]

After that you can manipulate it in any way you like by accessing it this:

[image: The result]

If you output just the string by itself then chrome will not truncate it.

Or if you want to be more direct, just use `console.log(temp1[0].text)`.